# Unable to reset() in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html code below:

```html
<div class="row">
    <form class="col-xs-6" id="add-car-form" method="post" action="add_cars.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="car-name">ADD CAR</label>
            <input type="text" name="car_name" class="form-control" required> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="add car">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The Javascript code with AJAX inside following:

```js
$('#add-car-form').submit(function (e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var postData=$(this).serialize();
    var url=$(this).attr('action');

    $.post(url,postData, function (php_table_data){
        $('#car-result').html(php_table_data);
        $('#add-car-form')[0][0].reset();
    });

});
```

The input element never resseting. I tried to put an id in my input element and targeting with `reset()` function but neither worked.
Any help from you is welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('#add-car-form')[0][0].val("");`

`$('#add-car-form').find("input[type=text]").val("");` will clear all text inputs in the form

jQuery does not have a `reset()` method, but js does, so if you want to use `reset()` you should use 
`document.getElementById('#add-car-form')[0][0].reset()`